# Why does my express.js app never loads?

Tags: node.js

I did everything as specified here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

When I try to reach my domain, and append :3000 to the end, it just never loads (timeout).

Comment: Paste some code

Comment: Questions about code MUST include the relevant portions of the code and must describe what debugging steps you have taken to diagnose what is going on and rule some things in or out. Did you run your app?  Did you verify using OS tools that it is running and listening on the desired port?  How do you attempt to contact it?  Do you know your DNS entry is working?  Do you know your server is reachable from the client location you are using? Questions that just say "my app doesn't work" and show no effort to collect information and diagnose what is going on are not very useful here for us or you.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything specified on https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html and it didn't work then it must mean that the tutorial is incorrect.

If, on the other hand, you didn't do everything as specified in the tutorial (which we will never know since you didn't post what you actually did) then you should make sure to follow the tutorial more closely because it doesn't look incorrect.

The reasons why trying to reach a random domain on a random port times out can be:

- wrong port
- wrong domain
- bad DNS record
- misconfigured DNS resolver
- firewall rules
- server not listening
- server listening on a different port
- server listening on a different interface

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't provide enough information for a better answer, with that said the most likely issue is that you never actually executed the JavaScript file you created. You'll want to make sure Node is installed and run:

```
nodejs app.js
```

Keep in mind that in some distros `node` doesn't exist, but `nodejs` does, when installing node from a package manager or other installer.

*EDIT*

There are other potential issues you'd run into if you don't have port 3000 opened up if you're not running it on localhost.